# Why do I get this java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error in running this program?

Tags: java

```
    String fullWord;
    String firstWord;
    String secondWord;
    String thirdWord;
    String fourthWord;

    int firstPositionOfAsterisk;
    int secondPositionOfAsterisk;
    int thirdPositionOfAsterisk;
    int fullWordCharacters;
    int firstWordCharacters;
    int secondWordCharacters;
    int thirdWordCharacters;
    int fourthWordCharacters;

    char lastLetterFirstWord;


    // I will prompt the user to enter four words seperated by a *
    fullWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter four words: ");

    // I will use the position of the * to make things easier
    firstPositionOfAsterisk = fullWord.indexOf("*");

    firstWord = fullWord.substring(0, firstPositionOfAsterisk);

    secondPositionOfAsterisk = firstWord.indexOf("*");

    secondWord = fullWord.substring(firstPositionOfAsterisk + 1, secondPositionOfAsterisk);

    thirdPositionOfAsterisk = secondWord.indexOf("*");

    thirdWord = fullWord.substring(secondPositionOfAsterisk + 1, thirdPositionOfAsterisk);

    fourthWord = fullWord.substring(thirdPositionOfAsterisk + 1);

    firstWordCharacters = firstWord.length();
    System.out.println(firstWord +" has a length of " + firstWordCharacters + " characters" );


    secondWordCharacters = secondWord.length();
    System.out.println(secondWord +" has length of " + secondWordCharacters + " characters" );

    thirdWordCharacters = thirdWord.length();
    System.out.println(thirdWord +" has length of " + thirdWordCharacters + " characters" );

    fourthWordCharacters = fourthWord.length();
    System.out.println(fourthWord +" has length of " + fourthWordCharacters + " characters" );

    lastLetterFirstWord = firstWord.charAt(firstPositionOfAsterisk - 1);
    System.out.println("The last letter of " + firstWord + "is " + lastLetterFirstWord);

    fullWord = firstWord + secondWord + thirdWord + fourthWord;

    fullWordCharacters = fullWord.length();
    System.out.println(firstWord +", " + secondWord + ", " + thirdWord + ", " + fourthWord + "has length of" + fullWordCharacters);
```

I'm trying to get the user to enter 4 words seperated by an "*" for example She*will*call*back and I want an output like like this

She has length 3
will has length 4
call has length 4
back has length 4

The * symbols were found at positions: 3, 8, and 13

The last character of she is s

The length of She, will, call, and back is 15

But I keep getting this java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error. How do I fix this?

This line crashes the program

secondWord = fullWord.substring(firstPositionOfAsterisk + 1, secondPositionOfAsterisk);

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. read this.. [String.substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

And you'll see that

```
throws
   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.
```

the important part is ***or beginIndex is larger than endIndex***

probably your `secondPositionOfAsterisk` is getting a negative (-1) value

Answer (score 0):

```
firstWord = fullWord.substring(0, firstPositionOfAsterisk);
```

The above takes the first part of the string up to the first asterisk, thus it won't contain an asterisk. So this will return `-1`:

```
secondPositionOfAsterisk = firstWord.indexOf("*");
```

Then this will fail: (because `-1` is not a valid index)

```
secondWord = fullWord.substring(firstPositionOfAsterisk + 1, secondPositionOfAsterisk);
```

I think this:

```
secondPositionOfAsterisk = firstWord.indexOf("*");
```

should be

```
int offset = firstWord.length()+1;
secondPositionOfAsterisk = firstWord.indexOf("*", offset);
```

or something like that.

Personally I think [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a way better option.